# How to calculate corners of a rectangle based on Cartesian coordinates

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, cartesian

I would like to draw a rectangle based on a center point lat and lon assuming a given length and width, let's say 4.5m and 1.5m, respectively. I guess, we need the bearing too. I've made a simulation by drawing a rectangle on Google Earth, getting the positions and putting them on my code. However, I need something automatic. My question is how can I link the Cartesian coordinates to those four points (rectangle) in meters.

Here is my code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [41.404928,  41.404936,  41.404951,  41.404943]
lon_point_list = [2.177339,   2.177331,   2.177353,   2.177365]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
import folium
m = folium.Map([41.4049364, 2.1773560], zoom_start=20)
folium.GeoJson(polygon_geom).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
```

I would like this:

[image]

I know this is basic trigonometry. If I split the rectsngle into triangles, we can find the different points. I know it is basic for simple exercises, however, I don't know of it changes when using Cartesian coordinates. Then, my goal is to get the points A, B, C and D, knowing the center of the rectangle in latitude and longitude, length and width.

[image]

Comment: Why are you looking for triangles? Find the equation of the line from the start point given the bearing https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471121/given-a-point-x-y-z-and-an-angle-bearing-distance-calculate-the-end-point-x-y, trim to length and copy parallel https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-parallel-perpendicular.html then join the loose ends (one line segment needs to be flipped).

Comment: You can't use Cartesian math on angular coordinate values (lat/lon degrees).  If you you did construct a rectangle, using haversine or geodesic functions, it would appear as a trapezoid on a Plate Carrée geographic map and potentially anything, with any rotation, with a projected map.

Comment: @MichaelStimson does it apply for lat/lon values? or should I consider the Earth's radius? the rectangle on the map was manually constructed since I don't have the real coordinates of the corners, which approach do you recommend me?

Comment: The distortion on an object of that size is going to be minimal but Vince is right in that you should construct the polygon in a projected CRS, where linear measurements have meaning, and project it to geographic. Web mercator EPSG:3857 would be a viable choice for the projected CRS. Another viable option is to have the polygon created and ready in memory and then copy/rotate/displace to suit with an affine transformation https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AffineTransformation.html